# Display/theme problems after reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04.02

Tags: display, themes, gimp, window-buttons

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu because I changed the permissions of a folder I shouldn't have. Ever since then I've had an issue with the way my range sliders and buttons are displayed in some applications, most noticeably GIMP.

The range sliders and buttons from my theme should look like the picture. I reinstalled 3 times, even going as far as completely wiping the hard drive just to be sure it wasn't something that was happening during the install process but nothing has changed.

I know it doesn't affect performance, but to me if there's one problem I can see then who knows what else might be going wrong so can anyone please tell me what could cause this to happen?

[image: Both range sliders side-by-side]

Answer (score 1):

Okay so in case anyone is interested I figured out what the problem is: It seems that when I reinstalled Ubuntu the package `gtk2-engines-pixbuf`, which controls all of the `pixmap` parts of themes, wasn't installed. I don't remember installing it manually the 1st time around, but if it doesn't come with Ubuntu then I must have. I just ran the following command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```